# React Native Expo Web Slider

Tags: react-native, slider, expo

Is there a good alternative to Slider that is similar and works for expo web.  Currently it seems like Slider does not work with expo web.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider

Comment: If you throw that in the answers I will mark it as correct.  It shows only android and ios in the readme, but it seems to be working for web also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for [react-native-slider](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider) in Expo